# AD Domain Controller won't allow incoming connections on other subnets?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I'm currently working on setting up an active directory domain controller at one location, with my clients connecting to the server via other subnets. I am running Windows Server 2019, with Windows 10 clients connecting to the server. I currently have the domain controller working internally, but I am having connectivity issues when connecting from external networks.

My local network (where the DC resides) is 192.168.1.1, where my other locations have been changed to 192.168.2.1 and so on. For example, client workstations need to connect from 2.1 subnet to the 1.1. I have a VPN server with OpenVPN on the 1.1 router (local network), and I have been connecting to that VPN server with client machines running OpenVPN. I can ping and traceroute the domain controller from client workstations when they are connected to the VPN, but I cannot connect to the controller. The Windows machines throw an error "An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain "totaltech.company" could not be contacted, ensure that the domain name is typed correctly".

I am new to this, but I appreciate any thoughts on the issue. I'm sure it could just be something simple on the DC side. Thanks!

Comment: What do the clients use for DNS, both when they're connected to the VPN and when they're not.

Comment: They are using the local Domain Controller's IP for DNS (192.168.1.222)